# How to change jquery accordion header background colors?

Tags: jquery-ui

Experts,

how to change the accordion menu header colors ? which style class name is this ? and how to set default selected tab ?

Please see the URL:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Here i need to select section 2 when i am opening menu...

Please help me out to get changes.

Comment: http://helpdesk.toitl.com/?w=accordion_color_header this link explains what you need

Answer (score 14):

In order to change the background color of the header, in the css, identify the accordion header class name and then change the background property like so:

```
.ui-accordion-header{
   background:black;
}
```

In order to set the active index to 2, use the api: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Accordion

Here you will find that you just have to call .accordion( "activate" , index ) on your jquery accordion object.

Comment: Thanks.  I had been failing for quite some time using background-color.  Switching it to background worked for me! doh!

Answer (score 2):

A quick inspection tells me that you have to modify the css declaration of

```
.ui-state-active a, .ui-state-active a:link, .ui-state-active a:visited
```

and

```
.ui-state-default a, .ui-state-default a:link, .ui-state-default a:visited
```

As for the default selected tab you could do something like below:

```
$('#myAccordionId').accordion({}).accordion("activate" , indexOrSelector) //index in your case would be 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I did this and it helps:

```
#accordion h3{ 
  background:none;
  background-color:yellow;         
}
```

First reset the main color then set the favorite color.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('HEADER').css('color', '#FF0000');
```

or

```
document.querySelector('HEADER').style.color = '#FF0000';
```